# With Necropotence, would I keep playing even with no library?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In MTG, I know if I'm not able to draw on my draw step I lose, but what if I had [Necropotence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNecropotence%5d) out; that lets me skip my draw step. Would I be able to continue playing the game?

I'm just curious because I'm not sure how that would work in play. I'm not too familiar with priorities, like who has it, who gets and when it changes. But I was thinking if I could skip my draw step I wouldn't have to draw therefore wouldn't lose because I can't draw.

Comment: You also don't lose if, for some reason, you choose to use the activated ability (unless you have only one life point).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are correct that if you control a Necropotence, you will not lose the game during your draw step, because you will skip your draw step entirely, and you can keep playing until the game ends some other way.

You say "I know if I'm not able to draw on my draw step I lose", but it would be more accurate to say that you lose if you are instructed to draw from an empty library at any time, during your draw step or otherwise.

From the Comprehensive Rules:

> 120.4. A player who attempts to draw a card from a library with no cards in it loses the game the next time a player would receive priority. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.)
>
> 120.5. If an effect moves cards from a player’s library to that player’s hand without using the word “draw,” the player has not drawn those cards. This makes a difference for abilities that trigger on drawing cards and effects that replace card draws, as well as if the player’s library is empty.

Comment: do you lose if you must discard from an empty library?

Comment: @tuskiomi No, it only applies to when you try to draw a card.

Answer (score 4):

As [Murgatroid mentioned](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/43112/9999), you don't lose until you have to draw from an empty library.

Since Necropotence causes you to skip your draw step, you won't lose from that.  However, you can still lose from effects that cause you to draw a card, such as either of the first two abilities of [Jace Beleren](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%20Beleren%5d) or [Sign in Blood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSign%20in%20Blood%5d) or if you control [Baleful Force](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBaleful%20Force%5d).